# Raspberrypi and PCA9685 no bus detected

Tags: servo

I'm trying to follow an [adafruit servos tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-servo-driver-with-raspberry-pi/overview?view=all) to control servo motor from my raspberrypi.

My PCA9685 seems on (the green led is power up) and i attached two servos to it. I cabled as in the tutorial, so the VCC is attached to the arduino with the ground (I think i so other possibilities). I made the alimentation myself from a 5V 0.4A.

[image: PCA9685]

[image: Rpi&PCA9685]

The pins have connected are:

```
 _______________
|..X..........
|XXX..........
|
```

When i use i2cdetect i got empty adresses:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Adafruit_Python_PCA9685 $ i2cdetect -y 1
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
 00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
 10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
 20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
 30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
 40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
 50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
 60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
 70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

So i'm not sure if it's

- my welding that are bad (i didn't weld every pin)
- my alimentation that isn't strong enough
- or if i'm missing something else.

Thanks alot.

EDIT:

I tried running:

```
echo -n 1 > /sys/module/i2c_bcm2708/parameters/combined
```

and in /etc/modprobe.d/i2c.conf :

```
options i2c-bcm2708 combined=1
```

and doing a reboot, but it didn't work and i still have no adresses showing up.

Result after installing :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install pigpio python-pigpio python3-pigpio

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pigs mg 2 mg 3
4
4
```

Comment: There's a line you may have to type in terminal to get I2C to work -- see this forum post: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=15840&start=25

Comment: sudo sh -c 'echo -n 1 > /sys/module/i2c_bcm2708/parameters/combined'

Comment: Why do you have a wire connected to OE? If you are externally driving OE you will change the logic for the output pins. Leave it float, it's pulled up on the board.

Comment: I'm not and it's not connected, it's the photo that's show that.
My connected pins are GND - SCL - SCA - VCC

Comment: The device is not correctly connected to the Pi.  We need a photo showing the I2C wires between the Pi and the device.

Comment: Sorry for that, i've added the picture and a little description of the pins have connected. Thanks @joan

Comment: The connections look correct: White 3V3, red SDA, brown SCL, black Ground.  That leaves a broken wire (i.e. no continuity) or some software has placed the GPIO in the wrong mode.  Could you report the result of the following pigs command? `sudo pigpiod` then `pigs mg 2 mg 3`.

Comment: The GPIO are in the correct mode.  That leaves the wiring or the device is bust.  Your first photo shows a red wire connected to ground of the power block.  If the red wire was +ve you may have damaged the device.

Comment: The red wire is connected to ground, and the black one to V+. So it shouldn't be a trouble.